# Eclipse NDK Path setting on Ubuntu

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, android-ndk

I have tried to build an Android Application using ndk on Eclipse, but console shows that ndk-build not found. I use Ubuntu and have already set PATH variable.

I set my PATH variable in this way.

```
export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=<path/to/ndkexport
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT
```

And when I typed 'which ndk-build', I could see the ndk directory path. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Eclipse, right click on your project, select Properties->Environment->Add, set variable name to PATH, type in 'echo $PATH' in terminal, set the variable value to the result plus your ndk directory. Then it will work.